Android 13 How to save image in galery .Net MAUI
I'm creating a project in .Net MAUI that takes photos and I would like to know how can I save it in a gallery by creating a folder.
I've seen that Google has changed its permissions.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!-- Required only if your app needs to access images or photos that other apps created -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<!-- Required only if your app needs to access videos that other apps created -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
</queries>

This is the code:
string sGpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);

// Crear la ruta completa del archivo
var folderPath = Path.Combine(sGpath, "GPV2");

photo.FileName = $ "{vf.IdVisita}_{DateTime.Now:yy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss}.jpg";
string uniqueFileName = $ "{vf.IdVisita}_{DateTime.Now:yy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss}.jpg";

string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, photo.FileName);

if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath)) {
  Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
}

using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();

Console.WriteLine($ "Archivo guardado en {filePath}");

vf.Titulo = uniqueFileName;
using(FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath)) {
  vf.Foto = ReadFully(fileStream);
}

The path in which it is saved for me is

/data/user/0/com.companyname.photov2/files/Pictures/GPV2/1_24_05_30_10_53_48.jpg

Even with that it doesn't keep me in gallery, how can I do it?

You can’t just write to a system folder.  Android provides Media APIs for adding images to the system gallery

@Jason Which API can be useful to me? e.g. Media plugin?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74073402/xamarin-forms-move-image-to-gallery-in-android-12-and-above

You can take a picture using Android and save it in the gallery. So, in Android 11 and newer, you will request storage access from your app, use a custom folder, and with MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync save files in that folder. So the path will be something like this /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/GPV2/<unique_file_name>.jpg

@BobSmith How Can I request storage acces ? with Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Media>()? This doesn't work

You can use the following code to save the image stream to gallery of your android device.
    public static class ImageSaveHelper
    {
        public static async Task SaveImage(Stream imageStream)
        {
            using var stream = imageStream;
            using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

            stream.Position = 0;
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

#if ANDROID
var context = Platform.CurrentActivity;

    if (OperatingSystem.IsAndroidVersionAtLeast(29))
    {
        Android.Content.ContentResolver resolver = context.ContentResolver;
        Android.Content.ContentValues contentValues = new();
        contentValues.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.IMediaColumns.DisplayName, "image.png");
        contentValues.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.IMediaColumns.MimeType, "image/png");
        contentValues.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.IMediaColumns.RelativePath, "DCIM/" + "image");
        Android.Net.Uri imageUri = resolver.Insert(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, contentValues);
           
        var os = resolver.OpenOutputStream(imageUri);
        Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options options = new();
        options.InJustDecodeBounds = true;
        var bitmap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
        bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, os);
        os.Flush();
        os.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        Java.IO.File storagePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(storagePath.ToString(), "image.png");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, memoryStream.ToArray());
        var mediaScanIntent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
        mediaScanIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(path)));
        context.SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

#endif
        }

    }

Note:

How Can I request storage acces ? with
Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Media>()? This doesn't work

You need to add the following permissions if you want to save and read image to Gallery not Permissions.Media.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

From document Permissions, we know that permission Permissions.Media will always return Granted when checked or requested.
And you also need the following api on the maui:
PermissionStatus statusread = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
PermissionStatus statuswrite = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();


Any idea how to do this but in iOS?

Use the MediaPicker class to start the camera and take a picture, there's no need to complicate the process. Besides that you didn't have to think about how to handle deprecated permissions. If you created a custom folder, you'd have to save the captured photo stream into a File Path by placing it using await photoStream.CopyToAsync(newFileStream) function.
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Maui.Media;
using Microsoft.Maui.Storage;

public async Task TakeAndSavePhoto()
{
    // Request storage access (Android 11+)
    if (Runtime.OperatingSystem == OperatingSystem.Android && Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.R)
    {
        var permissionStatus = await MediaLibrary.RequestPermissionsAsync();
        if (permissionStatus != MediaLibraryPermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            // Handle permission denied scenario 
            return;
        }
    }

    // Create custom folder 
    string sGpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Pictures);
    var folderPath = Path.Combine(sGpath, "GPV2");
    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
    }

    // Capture photo
    FilePickerFileType captureFileType = new FilePickerFileType(PickFileType.Image);
    var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync(captureFileType);

    if (photo == null)
    {
        // Handle user cancellation or error 
        return;
    }

    // Save photo to custom folder 
    string uniqueFileName = $"{DateTime.Now:yy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss}.jpg";
    string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, uniqueFileName);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderPath))
    {
        using (var newFileStream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
        {
            await photo.OpenReadAsync().CopyToAsync(newFileStream);
        }
    }

    // Save photo to public gallery
    using (var photoStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        await MediaLibrary.SaveToAlbumAsync(photoStream, "GPV2 Photos"); // Replace with a descriptive album name
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Photo saved to gallery: {filePath}"); // Optional, for debugging
}

Remember to update your AndroidManifest.xml for Android 11 or higher
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

So the path will be something like this /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/GPV2/<unique_file_name>.jpg

Update 1
Check Permission Status
var mediaPermissionStatus = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Media>();

Here are the possible results:

Permissions.PermissionStatus.Granted: The user has already granted storage permission to your app.
Permissions.PermissionStatus.Denied: The user has denied storage permission.
Permissions.PermissionStatus.Revoked: The user has granted permission in the past but revoked it later.
Permissions.PermissionStatus.Unknown: The permission status is unknown.


Update 2
@Giorgio You need to add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for this to work.
Also set android:maxSdkVersion="28" for WRITE_PERMISSION
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28" />

Read these link for more information

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#max

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.manifest.permission.writeexternalstorage?view=net-android-34.0#android-manifest-permission-writeexternalstorage

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.manifest.permission?view=net-android-34.0



I have this error: MediaLibrary, Runtime, BuildVersionCodes, PickFileType doesn't exist

you have to import those packages

for example for Runtime is using ObjCRuntime; and you don't have it

@Giorgio Runtime is a built-in namespace so no import needed. MediaLibrary, PickFileType uses package Microsoft.Maui.Media and BuildVersionCodes uses Microsoft.Maui.Platform package respectively.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.media?view=net-maui-8.0 doesn't have MediaLibrary

@Giorgio you may ask it as different question (since its introduced in .NET 7.0 framework) as adding that part also in my answer will make it into too broad category and will be confusing for future readers.

could some moderator help me put it like that?

I am migrating my app to .net 8 framework, still I dont see this MediaLibrary under Microsoft.Maui.Media package. Does it really exist?
